# Setting the LANG environment variable for xfce

Tags: debian, environment-variables, xfce, desktop-environment, locale

I am on a multi user Debian Stretch system which has `en_US.UTF-8` as default locale, but I want `de_DE.UTF-8` for my user. I was able to set it for terminals, by adding `export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` to `~/.bashrc`.

The problem is that my X environment (with XFCE as window manager and lightdm as login manager) still uses the default locale, which isn't a surprise as `.bashrc` is just for bash. So I tried setting the variable in various other files:

#### ~/.xinitrc

This file doesn't seem to get executed at all.

#### ~/.config/xfce4/xinitrc

Setting the variable here didn't work either (no observed change in behaviour). Also, if I switch the window manager, I need to set it for the new one again, which isn't very appealing.

#### ~/.xsession

Setting the variable here presumably works, but I would also need to start the window manager here, so I'm hoping to find a better place.

#### ~/.pam_environment

Seems to be ignored on Debian

#### ~/.xsessionrc

Setting environment variables here actually seems to work, but it looks like `LANG` is set to `en_US.UTF-8` later in the startup process.

#### ~/.i18n

Setting a language here doesn't seem to work.

It seems like all these aren't the right place to set the `LANG` variable. Where should I set it, to get the desired result?

Comment: `~/.pam_environment` is read by default on Debian. Did you write `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` or `export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`? `export` is wrong there, this isn't a shell script, just a list of `VARIABLE=value` lines.

Comment: I wrote `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`. I also tried `TEST=something` to be sure that `LANG` isn't  overwritten somewhere else. However, I `TEST` wasn't set on either physical or X terminals.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem that the language is not correctly set by lightdm (see [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=765077)).
Adding the LANG exports to *both* .bashrc and .xsessionrc did the trick for me. I export to LANG, LANGUAGE and LC_ALL to be sure.

Comment: I tried exporting LANG, LANGUAGE and LC_ALL in .bashrc, .xsessionrc and .config/locale.conf (on archlinux) and it still does not apply.

Comment: @bparker: In what context? Using [Thunderbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird)?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen XFCE itself. I don't remember how I fixed it but I only have a .dmrc file now so that must have been it (even though others said it doesn't work?) But I can't find any other files on my system (user or root) that have my locale in it and it's working

Answer (score 1):

Setting `~/.dmrc` works on Arch/Manjaro

```
$ cat ~/.dmrc 
[Desktop]
Session=xfce4
Language=en_US.utf8
```

This is mentioned in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale):

> LightDM will automatically use accountsservice to set a user's locale if it is installed. Otherwise, LightDM stores the user session configuration in ~/.dmrc. It is possible that an unwanted locale setting is retrieved from there as well.